# why the vagrant windows can ping but can't access in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

i spend a hold day to build the vagrant env on the windows ,and use the rbenv build the ruby env & install the rails !

evrythings ok,but when i start the rails s found i can't access on the chrome,then i use the ubuntu links to ping the 127.0.0.1:3000 it's ok,but ping the 192.168.10.10:3000 told me the connection refused!

[image]

that's my vagrantfile setting ,just only setting the private_network ip

anyone else can tell me how to resolv the problem?

Comment: Did you check for possible firewall settings?

Comment: How do you "*ping the 127.0.0.1:3000*" and "*192.168.10.10:3000*"? ICMP Ping does not connect on specific port.

Comment: telnet localhost 3000

Comment: thanks!,i found on windows the rails have to use ```-b 0.0.0.0```to listen the 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You need a forwading port like that :

```js
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
auto_correct: true
```

Add auto_correct if you aren't sure that the 3000 port is available on host...

Comment: thanks!,i found on windows the rails have to use ```-b 0.0.0.0```to listen the 0.0.0.0